# Better way to generate array of all letters in the alphabet

Tags: java, alphabet

Right now I'm doing

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    alphabet[c - 'a'] = c;
}
```

but is there a better way to do it? Similar to Scala's `'a' to 'z'`

Comment: Can you specify the use-case. Where do you need the array?

Comment: What do you mean by "better". is `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray()` better?

Comment: There is no "better" way per se. Even Scala's construct will use a loop to generate the array underneath.

Comment: Note that the above somewhat artificially depends on the fact that all lower-case Roman letters in ASCII/Unicode are contiguous.  It would not work, eg, with EBCDIC.

Comment: By better, I just mean for the code to look nicer. I don't care much for the performance.

Comment: @HotLicks The question pertains to Java, to the character encoding is UTF-16.

Comment: Which alphabet? There are many more than you might think.

Comment: @Raedwald - But the above technique will fall apart if you go from 'a' to 'å'.

Comment: in my humble opinion (based on aesthetics), your original solution is better than all the ones from the answers. If typing all the 26 characters by hand does not annoy you at least slightly, I hereby suspect you of really bad copy and paste programming style.

Comment: @Pshemo, fge. Shorter.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

I think that this ends up a little cleaner, you don't have to deal with the subtraction and indexing:

```
char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
```

Comment: And you can easily add additional characters as desired.

Comment: Ah, figured there might've been a cleaner way to do it without typing everything out or loops. :( I suppose I'll go with this one. Thanks!

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Java source files _are_ Unicode (so, in a string literal, that's what you have and that's all you can add).

Comment: Swift 2: let alphabet = Array("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters)

Comment: Would be nice of that string constant was available somewhere (commons or spring or jdk) already.

Comment: @Thilo possibly, but not all users are likely to use the *same* alphabet, so then you are in the tricky situation of "Do we store all alphabets as constants?" or "Can we even do that reasonably since some alphabets are very large?"

Comment: How do you ensure that no latter is omitted? E.g. when reading/reviewing code like this?

Answer (score 58):

```
char[] LowerCaseAlphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

char[] UpperCaseAlphabet = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
```

Comment: I actually wanted this! Thanks for helping me copy paste :)

Answer (score 27):

This `getAlphabet` method uses a similar technique as the one described this the question to generate alphabets for arbitrary languages.

Define any languages an enum, and call `getAlphabet`.

```
char[] armenianAlphabet = getAlphabet(LocaleLanguage.ARMENIAN);
char[] russianAlphabet = getAlphabet(LocaleLanguage.RUSSIAN);

// get uppercase alphabet 
char[] currentAlphabet = getAlphabet(true);
    
System.out.println(armenianAlphabet);
System.out.println(russianAlphabet);
System.out.println(currentAlphabet);
```

#### Result

> I/System.out: աբգդեզէըթժիլխծկհձղճմյնշոչպջռսվտրցւփքօֆ
>
> I/System.out: абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
>
> I/System.out: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

```
private char[] getAlphabet() {
    return getAlphabet(false);
}

private char[] getAlphabet(boolean flagToUpperCase) {
    Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    LocaleLanguage language = LocaleLanguage.getLocalLanguage(locale);
    return getAlphabet(language, flagToUpperCase);
}

private char[] getAlphabet(LocaleLanguage localeLanguage, boolean flagToUpperCase) {
    if (localeLanguage == null)
        localeLanguage = LocaleLanguage.ENGLISH;

    char firstLetter = localeLanguage.getFirstLetter();
    char lastLetter = localeLanguage.getLastLetter();
    int alphabetSize = lastLetter - firstLetter + 1;

    char[] alphabet = new char[alphabetSize];

    for (int index = 0; index < alphabetSize; index++) {
        alphabet[index] = (char) (index + firstLetter);
    }

    if (flagToUpperCase) {
        alphabet = new String(alphabet).toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    }

    return alphabet;
}

private enum LocaleLanguage {
    ARMENIAN(new Locale("hy"), 'ա', 'ֆ'),
    RUSSIAN(new Locale("ru"), 'а','я'),
    ENGLISH(new Locale("en"), 'a','z');

    private final Locale mLocale;
    private final char mFirstLetter;
    private final char mLastLetter;

    LocaleLanguage(Locale locale, char firstLetter, char lastLetter) {
        this.mLocale = locale;
        this.mFirstLetter = firstLetter;
        this.mLastLetter = lastLetter;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return mLocale;
    }

    public char getFirstLetter() {
        return mFirstLetter;
    }

    public char getLastLetter() {
        return mLastLetter;
    }

    public String getDisplayLanguage() {
        return getLocale().getDisplayLanguage();
    }

    public String getDisplayLanguage(LocaleLanguage locale) {
        return getLocale().getDisplayLanguage(locale.getLocale());
    }

    @Nullable
    public static LocaleLanguage getLocalLanguage(Locale locale) {
        if (locale == null)
            return LocaleLanguage.ENGLISH;

        for (LocaleLanguage localeLanguage : LocaleLanguage.values()) {
            if (localeLanguage.getLocale().getLanguage().equals(locale.getLanguage()))
                return localeLanguage;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a fun Unicode solution:

```
int charAmount = 'z' - 'a' + 1;

char[] alpha = new char[charAmount];
for(int i = 0; i < charAmount ; i++){
    alpha[i] = (char)('a' + i);
}

System.out.println(alpha); //abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

This generates a lower-cased version of alphabet.
If you want upper-cased, you can replace 'a' with 'A' at `('a' + i)`.

Comment: `char` holds a UTF-16 unit-code, one or two of which make a Unicode codepoint. Calling it ASCII distracts from these facts.

Comment: I will vote this up if you also add `^` or at least `~`

Comment: `k` is redundant. Just do `'a' + i`.

Comment: Hello. I updated your example to eliminate "magic numbers" (see: [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882)). If you don't agree with it feel free to rollback my edit.

Answer (score 17):

In Java 8 with Stream API, you can do this.

```
IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z').mapToObj(var -> (char) var).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Java 8

```
char[] charArray = IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
    .mapToObj(c -> "" + (char) c).collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

Comment: Hm yes - it seems there is no good solution for this using streams, as there is no CharStream. If you add a bit of explanation I might even upvote, although I wouldn't recommend this approach - it is in no way better than the loops.

Comment: @Hulk: sure but you could return a `Stream<Character> CharStream = IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z').mapToObj(c -> (char) c);` and use that from that point on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8

Comment: @techouse sure, but the OP wanted a `char[]` - for that, the boxing and unboxing cannot be avoided with streams.

Answer (score 6):

```
static String[] AlphabetWithDigits = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this once I'm sure you will get `a` to `z` alphabets:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    al.add(c);
}
System.out.println(al);'
```

Answer (score 4):

with [io.vavr](http://www.vavr.io/)

```
public static char[] alphanumericAlphabet() {
    return CharSeq
            .rangeClosed('0','9')
            .appendAll(CharSeq.rangeClosed('a','z'))
            .appendAll(CharSeq.rangeClosed('A','Z'))
            .toCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few alternatives based on [@tom thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6639094/tom-thomas)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38586500/6045800).

### Character Array:

```
char[] list = IntStream.concat(
                IntStream.rangeClosed('0', '9'),
                IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
        ).mapToObj(c -> (char) c+"").collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

### String Array:

*Note: Won't work correctly if your delimiter is one of the values, too.*

```
String[] list = IntStream.concat(
                IntStream.rangeClosed('0', '9'),
                IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
        ).mapToObj(c -> (char) c+",").collect(Collectors.joining()).split(",");
```

### String List:

*Note: Won't work correctly if your delimiter is one of the values, too.*

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(IntStream.concat(
                IntStream.rangeClosed('0', '9'),
                IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
        ).mapToObj(c -> (char) c+",").collect(Collectors.joining()).split(","));
```

Answer (score 3):

For Android developers searching for a [image]Kotlin solution and ending up here:

```kotlin
// Creates List<Char>
val chars1 = ('a'..'z').toList()
```

```kotlin
// Creates Array<Char> (boxed)
val chars2 = ('a'..'z').toList().toTypedArray()
```

```kotlin
// Creates CharArray (unboxed)
val chars3 = CharArray(26) { 'a' + it }
```

```kotlin
// Creates CharArray (unboxed)
val chars4 = ('a'..'z').toArray()
fun CharRange.toArray() = CharArray(count()) { 'a' + it }
```

To see what I mean by "boxed" and "unboxed" see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090808/8583692).
Many thanks to [this Kotlin discussion thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/arrays-from-ranges/5216).

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] abc = new char[26];

for(int i = 0; i<26;i++) {
    abc[i] = (char)('a'+i);
}
```

Comment: The inner cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @shmosel No it's not

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu It was when I wrote that

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 streams

```
  char [] alphabets = Stream.iterate('a' , x -> (char)(x + 1))
            .limit(26)
            .map(c -> c.toString())
            .reduce("", (u , v) -> u + v).toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get uppercase letters in addition to lower case letters, you could also do the following:

```
String alphabetWithUpper = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toUpperCase();
char[] letters = alphabetWithUpper.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
var alphabet = IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z')
    .boxed()
    .map(Character::toChars)
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .toList();
```

### Notes

- `rangeClosed()` in order to make it `'z'` inclusive
- `boxed()` in order to create a list from an `IntStream`
- `toList()` creates an unmodifiable list, but is apparently only  [available starting with Java 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674624/how-do-i-convert-a-java-8-intstream-to-a-list#answer-23674719)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Experiments{


List uptoChar(int i){
       char c='a'; 
        List list = new LinkedList();
         for(;;) {
           list.add(c);
       if(list.size()==i){
             break;
           }
       c++;
            }
        return list;
      } 

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Experiments experiments = new Experiments();
          System.out.println(experiments.uptoChar(26));
    }
```

Comment: Is this an intentional attempt at obfuscation? `for(;;)` with an external counter and `break`... and no check that `i>='a'`

Answer (score -6):

```
for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
{
    System.out.println(letter);
}
```