# String literal with toCharArray() producing garbage in Java

Tags: java, string, char, literals, garbage

I wanted to create a char array of the alphabet.  I looked at this post:

[Better way to generate array of all letters in the alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575840/better-way-to-generate-array-of-all-letters-in-the-alphabet)

which said this:

`char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();`

So in my code I have:

```
public class Alphabet {

private char[] letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

public String availableLetters(){

    return letters.toString();
   } 

}
```

When I call the function availableLetters() from main() and printit to the console, it outputs this garbage:

`[C@15db9742`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: garbage(Java) producing garbage. That's called productive garbage.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm just a newbie

Comment: There's no need to apologize, it's a valid question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass the char array to the String constructor or the static method `String.valueOf()` and return that instead.

Answer (score 5):

The array is correct, the problem is that you are not printing it correctly.

If you print your array one character at a time, you would get a correct result:

```
for (char c : letters) {
    System.out.print("'" + c + "' ");
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/ucoA7H)

Unfortunately, Java standard class library does not provide a meaningful override of `toString()` for arrays, causing a lot of trouble for programmers who are new to the language.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print it in array form, then use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

**BTW**: The `[C@15db9742` is not really garbage. It's what gets printed out when a class does not override the `toString()` method.

From [Object.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method. The toString method for class Object
>   returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
>   object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned
>   hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other
>   words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())